# IDictionary assignment shortcuts compiler feature or language feature?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

Through some random object creation today I came across this neat little shortcut for a `Dictionary<K, V>`.  Is the following assignment a compiler shortcut or is it a feature of `Dictionary<string, string>`.

```
IDictionary<string, string> items = { { "item1key", "item1value" } };
```

Looking at the source for `Dictionary<K, V>` I don't see anything offhand for how this works. Implementing all the interfaces for this class dot not allow me to perform a similar operation. Why is it that we can do it for a dictionary but not another type. For example, how does the compiler or language feature know that the first item is a key and the second item is the value. Or even more specific this same syntax can't be used for a `List<string>`

```
List<string> items = { "item1" };
```

So the first is valid, why?

I'm not necessarily trying to duplicate this but rather curious as to *why* it is the way it is. What makes a dictionary special in this case?

### Example that works

```
public class Button
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ButtonType Type { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> Items { get; set; }
    public bool RequiresSelected { get; set; }
}

var buttons = new List<Button>
    {
        new Button { 
            Items = {
                        {"button1", "Button 1"},
                        {"button2", "Button 2"},
                        {"button3", "Button 3"},
                    }, 
            Title = "3 Buttons", 
            Type = ButtonType.DropDown 
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax you've shown isn't valid in C#. You'd need:

```
IDictionary<string, string> items = new Dictionary<string, string>
    { { "item1key", "item1value" } };
```

At that point it's just a normal collection initializer, so the list equivalent would be:

```
List<string> items = new List<string> { "item1" };
```

EDIT: Let's see if my edit can beat yours. My guess is that you've seen something like:

```
var foo = new Foo {
    SomeDictionaryProperty = { 
         { "item1key", "item1value" }
    }
};
```

That's an *embedded* collection initializer, and can be used for lists too. It's not creating a *new* dictionary, it's adding to an existing one. The code above is equivalent to:

```
var tmp = new Foo();
tmp.SomeDictionaryProperty.Add("item1key", "item1value");
var foo = tmp;
```

Another example of it working:

```
var form = new Form {
    Controls = { new Label { Text = "Foo"}, new Label { Text = "Bar" } }
};
```

See section 7.6.10.2 of the C# 4 specification (Object Initializers) for more information. The important bit is this:

```
member-initializer:
    identifier   =   initializer-value

initializer-value:
    expression
    object-or-collection-initializer
```

So you can initialize a property to *either* be a specific value (in which case the setter will be used) *or* via an object/collection initializer, in which case the *getter* for the property will be used, and then setters or the Add method will be used for the body of the object/collection initializer.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Doing inline like my example doesn't compile - lemme put up my actual usage.

Comment: @BuildStarted: Not on my machine it doesn't, even with the VS11 beta compiler. Please show a short but *complete* program which works for you.

Comment: @BuildStarted: Have edited my post with a guess as to what you're doing :)

Comment: Ok, so it'd work with the list type if I used it in the same way as I am using the dictionary. So it's a compiler shortcut and not necessarily a feature of the language itself to shortcut assignments.

Comment: @BuildStarted: It's absolutely a feature of the language. The compiler is just implementing the language! It's not a feature of the .NET platform, per se, if that's what you mean. Very few things are compiler features without being language features - mostly around optimizations, warnings etc.

Comment: I should have known never to question your answers :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of C# compiler, and the dictionary is not special: any collection that supports `Add` can be initialized in this way. The details are in the section 7.6.10.3 of the [C# Language Specification 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029).

> The collection object to which a collection initializer is applied must be of a type that implements System.Collections.IEnumerable or a compile-time error occurs. For each specified element in order, the collection initializer invokes an Add method on the target object with the expression list of the element initializer as argument list, applying normal overload resolution for each invocation. Thus, the collection object must contain an applicable Add method for each element initializer.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful information from the language specifications on what is necessary to meet this requirement. This helps a lot in my understanding.